# Oracle select twice in the same table without duplicates

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select, duplicates

i have a table like that:

```
Table table: column A, column B
               1        A
               2        B
               3        C
```

And i want to execute a select like:

```
SELECT t.A, t2.A FROM table t, table t2 WHERE...
```

That select returns:

```
    t.A     t2.A
--------------------
     1       2
     2       1
```

But i want just

```
    t.A     t2.A
--------------------
     1       2
```

What can i do?

Thx.

Comment: `WHERE ...` probably needs to be more specific.

Comment: In part of query you write, can be implemented a cartesian product. Please use JOIN explicit notation and post completely your query.

Comment: Add `and t.A < t2.A` to your `where` clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your where condition is

```
SELECT t.A, t2.A FROM table t, table t2 
WHERE t.A < t2.A AND <OLD_CONDITION>
```

You will get each result only once.

Comment: This will remove all rows where they're equal, which may or may not be what's intended.

Comment: Sorry, the select is something like that: `SELECT t.A, t2.A FROM table t, table t2 WHERE (t.B LIKE t2.B) AND t.A <> t2.A`